# Multiple directions on the same Google Map on click

Tags: google-maps

I would like to reproduce a multi direction route sistem on the same Google Map like this website: http://hotelberna.com/en/where-we-are/

The same start point and multiple destinations. When I click on each final destination, then the map show me the new route.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must be talking about something like this, right?
http://jsfiddle.net/dm1o1ktf/ 

(a modified version of the [sample code in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple))

What you need is to trigger some function like calcRoute when you select a new location; in which you calculate the new route using the `directionsService`, like this:

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = "Mountain View, CA";
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
      origin:start,
      destination:end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi kaho, yes, something like that but instead of managing the map changing with a dropdown field I would do it with some buttons. Thanks anyway!